# Running indexhibit with a non-MySQL backend -- can it be done?

Tags: mysql, php, sql, drivers, cms

The version of the [Indexhibit](http://indexhibit.org/) PHP-based CMS that's available for public download has been [0.70 (or thereabouts)](http://indexhibit.org/forum/thread/760/) for around four years, and as far as I know, it's been a MySQL-only app for the entirety of that time.

AND YET: the [config file](http://bit.ly/qZuC3v) has a `sql` parameter in which 'mysql' is the default, and there's also a [database abstraction class sitting alone in a `db` directory](http://bit.ly/qoTyyE) ... these architectural hints suggest that [Eatock](http://eatock.com/) and [Vaska](http://www.tatiret.com/) (its authors) planned to enable one to connect the app to something other than MySQL -- or, more tantalizingly, they actually wrote such functionality but did not release it.

If you know of a non-MySQL backend for this handsomely accomplished and time-tested portfolio CMS, homebrew or otherwise, please tell me where I might get my hands on it.

Anything non-MySQL would be great; a PostgreSQL adapter would be specifically thrilling to obtain, but I'm not pedantic about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect fish2000 that it wasn't that the people planned to make a class for it but abstracted the database engine so that they could or someone could in future, what is your reason for not using mysql?

Comment: I was hoping someone would be like "yeah here's a link to the postgres adapter" but unfortunately your logic is sound; the fact that most programmers love saying things like "I wrote a database abstraction layer" to non-programmers, like when they're asked what they worked on last week, because it sounds cool.

Comment: But yes: in my efforts to win the hearts and minds of putative clients and employers, I had to cram a bunch of demos onto the same server instance that I have my portfolio and personal projects. The demos are mostly image-processing stuff in python... so not what the kids would call "web scale" w/r/t even modest scaling. python and color math are a workable recipe in desktop and academic-y single-user apps -- but so after some frantic optimization (which hopefully didn't coincide with HTTP requests from any fat cats) it runs OK but memory usage is now reportedly at 150%.

Comment: ... Which I am not sure how that mathematically works out and I'm sure I'll find out when it ceases to do so. Nevertheless. I want to exhume a super-old project that is frankenstiened together with indexhibit, and as such brings along its RDBMS myopia... I don't like MySQL, so having to spin up an instance will infuriate me and cause a bunch of memory problems (in that order) so I was hoping for an easy way out -- I have been doing python for 3 years now so I am way to jaded to hack up the PHP in the ancient app (I did 6 years of PHP so I earned my resentment)...

Comment: ... but so, swapping in a magic postgres driver file would have resolved the whole ass-ache. c'est la guerre. that's why, in a nutshell.